# Android Homescreen widget Animation

Tags: android, animation, widget, homebrew

## Android Homescreen widget Animation

I am trying to implement widget in android application.
There is
 one toggle button like signIn and signOut.it working great but can anyone help me how to apply animation on this button?? something like highlight or flip etc. is there any way or library then please suggest me.

Thank you in advance.